# 'Order' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, constructor, arguments

I'm getting 'Order' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments. So based on that error, I know it's in my public class Order. What am I overlooking? Thanks!

```
public class Order
{
    public int QuantityOrdered { get; set; }
    public double TotalPrice;
    public const double PRICEEACH = 19.95;

    virtual public double totalPrice
    {
        set
        {
            TotalPrice = QuantityOrdered * PRICEEACH;
        }
    }
}

public class ShippedOrder : Order
{
    public const double SHIPPINGFEE = 4.00; 
    public override double totalPrice
    {
        set
        {
            totalPrice = base.TotalPrice + SHIPPINGFEE;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you were prodded to produce the constructors of the class, and has failed to do so and instead decided to "sleep on it", I'm going to close this question as not-a-real-question to prevent people spending time on it until you fix the question. You really need to produce the constructor(s) of the order class in the code above or nobody has any chance of helping you.

Comment: Since some people work two jobs while trying to better themselves, sometimes they need sleep Lasse. I apologize for being human. But I was able to figure out the problem. Yes I didn't have any arguments being passed in my Main program. Once I passed those into the Class Order, it worked. Thanks for everyone that helped me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There has to be a constructor in the Order class you haven't listed in the code you provided.

When you do not define any constructors for a class, you're given an implicit parameterless constructor by the compiler.

However, when you add a constructor that takes a parameter, ex. `public Order(string someString) {}`, you lose this implicit constructor.

What you need to do is one of the following:

1. Add an explicit parameterless constructor, ex. `public Order() {}`
2. Update the code that's instantiating the Order object to pass the parameter it's looking for, ex. `new Order(someString)`
3. Remove the constructor(s) from Order that expect parameters.

Comment: Thanks Dan. It was a simple mistake. I didn't see any arguments being passed in my Main. I was staying too focused in the Order class that I overlooked it. #2 was the fix.

Answer (score 2):

The only way you can receive that error message is if you either have:

1. A constructor that takes 1 or more arguments in your class.
2. A constructor that takes 0 arguments, but is either protected or private and you are attempting to call the constructor outside of access.